# GWT parsing JSON data with JsonUtils

Tags: java, json, gwt

I am starting a GWT app in which I want to parse JSON data. Eventually, I will want to send HTTP requests to retrieve JSON from the server, but first thing first, I'm trying to just get GWT to parse JSON at all, and I'm having troubles.

I have read the docs at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html and I don't really understand it :(

Based on the docs, I have written this simple client-side class:

```
public class MyWebApp implements EntryPoint {

  private String personJson = "{ \"firstName\" : \"Jimmy\", \"lastName\" : \"Webber\" }";

  /**
   * This is the entry point method.
   */
  public void onModuleLoad() {

    Customer c = MyWebApp.parseJson(personJson);

    final TextBox customerDetails = new TextBox();
    final TextBox control = new TextBox();
    customerDetails.setText(c.getFirstName());
    control.setText("This is some control text");

    RootPanel.get("customerContainer").add(customerDetails);
    RootPanel.get("control").add(control);

  }

  public static <T extends JavaScriptObject> T parseJson(String jsonStr) {
    return JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonStr);
  }

  static class Customer extends JavaScriptObject {

    // Overlay types always have protected, zero-arg ctors
    protected Customer() {
    }

    // Typically, methods on overlay types are JSNI
    public final native String getFirstName() /*-{ return this.FirstName; }-*/;

    public final native String getLastName() /*-{ return this.LastName;  }-*/;

    // Note, though, that methods aren't required to be JSNI
    public final String getFullName() {
        return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
    }
  }
}
```

It creates 2 text boxes, one of them correctly pre-populated with the string `This is some control text`, but the other just remains empty, where I would have expected `Jimmy`. I am getting no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the casing in the JSON data is wrong, causing the JSNI mapping to fail. If you change 'firstName' to 'FirstName', it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you have to retrieve data by send HTTP request.
I have already worked on this and have a good code for you.I hope this code will help you. 
I used the jar file from the link below 
json-simple-1.1.1.jar - Google Code

//Start Of class PNRAlgorithm
public class PNRAlgorithm extends JFrame
{

```
//Variable for PNR number
private String pnr = null;
private StringBuilder response = null;


//Constructor
PNRAlgorithm(String pnr) throws IOException
{
    this.pnr = pnr;
    getPnrResponse(pnr,"json");
}

//Method to get response from the JSON file
private  String getPnrResponse(String pnrNo, String format) throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{
    //Checking If textfield is empty
    if(pnr == null || pnrNo.trim().length() != 10)
    {
        //Some more validations like only numeric are used etc can be added.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid PNR");
    }
    else
    {
    //requesting the format of file from API
    format = format == null || format.trim().equals("") ? "json" : format;

    //More validations can be added like format is one of xml or json.
    //String endpoint = "http://railpnrapi.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/"+pnrNo+"/format/"+format;
    String endpoint = "http://api.erail.in/pnr?key=API_KEY&pnr="+pnr+"";

    HttpURLConnection request = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;

    try
    {
        URL endpointUrl = new URL(endpoint);
        request = (HttpURLConnection)endpointUrl.openConnection();
        request.setRequestMethod("GET");
        request.connect();

        rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));

        //string builder to concatenate the string data
        response = new StringBuilder();

        //string to recieve the data one by one
        String line = null;

        //creating the JsonBuilder
        StringBuilder jsonfile = null;

        //loop to recieve the data one by one
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //saving the response from API
             jsonfile = response.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String str = jsonfile.toString();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        //Map object to get the data from the JSON file
        Map jsonData = (Map) parser.parse(str);
        String status = (String)jsonData.get("status");
        if(status.equals("OK"))
        {
         Map result = (Map) jsonData.get("result");
         String pnrnum=(String)result.get("pnr");
         String train_no=(String)result.get("trainno");
         String train_name=(String)result.get("name");
         String doj=(String)result.get("journey");
         String fcode = (String) result.get("from");
         String tcode = (String) result.get("to");
         String boarding = (String) result.get("brdg");
         String c_pre = (String)result.get("chart");
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, no_psngs);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, number);
        ArrayList passengers =new ArrayList();
        passengers.addAll((ArrayList)result.get("passengers"));
        int no_psngs = passengers.size();
        int number = no_psngs;
        String[] sr = new String[number+1];
        String[] b_status= new String[number+1]; 
        String[] c_status= new String[number+1];
        for(int i=0; i<number ;i++)
         {
             Map pssng = (Map) passengers.get(i);
             sr[i] = (i+1) + "";
             b_status[i] = (String) pssng.get("bookingstatus");
             c_status[i] = (String) pssng.get("currentstatus");
         }

        //Constructor of PNRShow frame and sending the required parameters 
        PNRoutput pNRoutput = new PNRoutput( pnrnum,  train_no,  train_name,  doj,  fcode, tcode,boarding,no_psngs,c_pre,sr,b_status,c_status);


        Runner.runnerFrame.remove(this);
        Runner.runnerFrame.add(pNRoutput);
        pNRoutput.setBounds(10, 155, 978, 430);

    }

        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PNR Flushed");
        }
    } 

    catch (ParseException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(PNRAlgorithm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```